# What's the best way to disable image download in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

It is not disabled by default.

I have written a spider which consumes almost 2 GB of data per hour. Now I want to save my data consumption, images are of no use for me, so want to make sure they not being fetched.

Given that this is a P0 scenario, it should be a simple flag in `settings.py` but surprisingly from docs I couldn't find any. I found a lot of details about `ImagesPipeline`, enabling those pipelines, their storage etc, but no flag for people not interested in images. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Surely you can see what requests the spider is making? If not by default, you can probably turn up logging to see what's happening.

Comment: Per default scrapy only downloads the base page without any pictures, script etc.

Comment: @AKX Not sure I get your point, me checking logs wont change the behaviour. My question was simple, can be answer in 1 word: 'yes' or 'no'. "If yes then X is the name of the flag you need to set, if no this is the code+config you need to add to your project."

Comment: @ThomasStrub you are wrong its downloading the images, I saved the response to html file and opened offline , it has images

Comment: @ishandutta2007 "I saved the pages to html file and opened offline , it has images" – are you sure those images aren't referenced by absolute URLs? If you disconnect from the Internet, will they still load?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Your original question was "Is image download in scrapy disabled by default?". My comment was referring to the fact that you can see, via logs, if images are being actually downloaded, which answered that question.

Comment: @AKX Good point, but I double checked seeing your comment. It has images when not connected to internet and on hovering shows me path like `file:///?..`

Comment: “It has images when not connected to internet and on hovering shows me path like file:///?..”. And can you see the image files at that `file://` path? Did Scrapy download them there? (if so, they have to show up in the logs)

Comment: At this point, you should really consider creating a minimal spider to reproduce the issue, and include it in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Gallaecio No image is not opening, probably a sgv created on the fly or something. Anyways for now if you are assuring it is disabled by default then it should be fine. It would be great if could also point me to some ways to reduce data consumption by other means.

Comment: What’s the size of the HTML document in your file system?

Comment: @Gallaecio about 100k

Comment: @AKX I was talking about my original question only. My original question was an objective question which could have been answered with 'yes' or 'no', no the current question. Anyways never mind thanks for your two cents. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202200/discussion-between-gallaecio-and-ishandutta2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy does not download images unless you explicitly tell it to do it.

You can check in the run time logs the URLs that Scrapy downloads. If a image URL does not appear in the logs, it is not being downloaded, even if a webpage that contains images is downloaded.

When you open a downloaded page in a web browser, images are downloaded on the fly by the web browser. They do not come from the downloaded webpage, they are not (usually) embedded in the webpage, the webpage indicates where in the Internet they are, and the web browser downloads them to display them, but Scrapy does not.

The only exception would be that images are actually embedded in the HTML code, as base64. This is uncommon, and probably not your case. And when that happens, there is no way you can prevent their download, you cannot download a webpage excluding part of its content.

Comment: thanks for the comment , I don't see anything in logs. probably that uncommon case was my case, I will investigate more and confirm.